# Изменение объектов дочернего класса через массив указателей

Tags: c++, ооп, полиморфизм

Имеется родительский класс [peripheral.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzSmr.png). От него наследуются 2 дочерних класса: [keyboard.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYCjz.png) и [scanner.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT8vb.png). Вот схема:

> [image: схема]

В базовом классе **Peripheral** определены поля **cost** и **amount**. В классе **Keyboard** добавляется поле **keyNumber**, а в классе **Scanner** - **speed**.

Также в базовом классе определён виртуальный метод который позволяет вывести все поля, включая собственные, каждому классу.

```
virtual void Show() const;
```

Я хочу создать общий массив указателей и добавить туда указатели на все созданные во время выполнения программы объекты:

```
vector<Peripheral*> peripheral;
peripheral.push_back(new Peripheral());
peripheral.push_back(new Keyboard());
peripheral.push_back(new Scanner());
```

Если в будущем я захочу изменить поле объекта класса **Keyboard**, используя данный массив, то у меня ничего не получится, так как эти указатели типа **Peripheral***.

В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос: как **ГРАМОТНО** реализовать данную возможность. Пока что я решил эту задачу не очень красивым способом: я создал ещё один виртуальный метод в базовом классе, который в каждом дочернем классе реализуется по своему.

```
virtual void SetField(double value);
```

А если таких полей будет много? Что же тогда? Придётся создавать подобные методы.

Может, в учебниках встречали решение таких задач - буду очень рад. Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Я не силен в С++, но... Указатель типа Peripheral* нужно просто привести к указателю на нужный тип. Для этого можно в классе Peripheral сделать виртуальное свойство TypePeripheral и в соответствии с ним делать преобразование. Либо определять тип объекта, хранимого по указателю Peripheral* и соответственно делать преобразование.

Comment: Если я понял верно, то свойство TypePeripheral хранит тип объекта. И потом уже использовать, верно? Я делал и так, но потом подумал, что и этот вариант не очень хороший, так как для каждого объекта придётся такое свойство иметь. Я могу и ошибаться, так как я сам пока что в программировании не силён, но экспериментирую как могу)

Comment: Да TypePeripheral хранит тип объекта для каждого класса свой. Но можно и проверять тип объекта средствами языка (не знаю как в с++) В варианте с TypePeripheral - более наглядно для программиста. В варианте с проверкой типа - менее трудозатратно.

Comment: Да, пробовал и с введением в классе TypePeripheral, и средствами c++. Средствами c++ не получится, так как typeid() (вроде так), не всегда возвращает читаемый тип данных. Он может выдать peripheral12312. Вроде так. Но Всё равно спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется *сделать конкретное действие над `Peripheral`, если это `Keyboard`*, то это называется даункастингом, и в C++ для работы с типами в рантайме есть оператор dynamic_cast.

В частности, его версия для указателей выглядит так:

```
Keyboard *kb{dynamic_cast<Keyboard *>(peripheral[1])};
if(kb) kb->pressKey(Ctrl);
```

`dynamic_cast` указателя возвращает `nullptr`, если такое преобразование невозможно (например, `dynamic_cast<Keyboard *>(prh)`, когда `prh` есть на самом деле `Scanner *`).

Возможно еще делать даункастинг ссылок: `dynamic_cast<Keyboard &>(*(peripheral[1]))`. В этом случае, если тип у объекта другой, кидается `std::bad_cast` (кажется).

В другую сторону — `dynamic_cast<Peripheral *>(new Keyboard)` — это апкастинг.

Поэтому, например, если нужно что-то сделать со всеми клавиатурами в массиве указателей на устройства, нужно что-то:

```
for(auto prh: peripheral) {
    Keyboard *kb{dynamic_cast<Keyboard *>(prh)};
    if(kb) {
        kb-press(Enter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересная вещь. Надо изучить этот метод. Спасибо большое. Буду пробовать!